# magento installation did succeed but apache welcome page appears in frontend

Tags: centos, ssl, installation, certificate, magento

I have a VPS at ionos, a centos 8 os.
I have installed a LAMP, elsticsearch, rabbit etc...
I have a SSL EV for my domain at  namecheaped.com: ortie-bio.fr and [www.ortie-bio.fr](http://www.ortie-bio.fr)
I have followed this tuto to install Magento open source 2.4.2 :
https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/install-magento-2-4-on-centos-8/
At the end I did choose the composer installation, as describe in :
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html
Magento installation completed with success but when I go to ortie-bio.fr in my browser it appears the default apache welcome page...
I did uses the etc/httpd/conf directory for my certificates, perhaps instead of the etc/ssl directory but I have tested and it works, as you can see below with an index.html that I have put in my public_html directory : https://www.ortie-bio.fr/index.html
In my install commands I have :

```
--base-url=https://www.ortie-bio.fr/  --use-rewrites=1 --use-secure=1 --base-url-secure=https://www.ortie-bio.fr/ --use-secure-admin=1
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did do a lots of things by myself so I don't know what was the issue...
It was not the installation of the ssl certificate, the checker was ok:
https://decoder.link/sslchecker/ortie-bio.fr/443
I Reviewed my config files ssl.conf, vhost.conf, *.conf in the sites-availables directory,...
an *AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode* problem?
a redirection problem?... :
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9821/38/apache-redirect-to-https/
Must we install with http and go in the configuration of magento to configure the https? ...
https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/install-magento-2-4-on-centos-8/
I don't know what I did but now it works, sorry that nobody could help me and sorry I can't help anybody more precisely...